# Changing iOS and Android app's name and icon on the fly

Tags: android, ios, app-update

Okay, I know the title is a bit confusing so let me explain it a little bit more.

We have different groups of clients and they want to have their own app, meaning the app name, icon, splash screen and theme colour are customized. But the functionalities and features remain the same across the whole product line.

Of course, we can submit different app for different client. But the maintenance would be a nightmare to the development team - each new feature / bug fixes needed to be pushed to different branches and we need to do multiple app update. Furthermore, we need to do manual testing on all the variants. We do not want to go down this road.

As a developer, I want to have a generic app for app submission and update. But once the client signed up then we change the app name, icon and splash screen according to his settings. I know I can do the splash screen and theme color - just render a different image and RGB value from the server on login. But I do not know if there is way to changed the app name and icon after the app installation.

I have also done preliminary search on this question but the answer I got is a no. Since those answers are from 2011 so I wonder if the situation has changed or not.

Many Thanks!

P.S. I found a group of apps on App Store which cover the question I asked. It is called DropLocker. They have 14 variants but I guess they use the same code base. I wonder if there is an update, do they push it individually or there is a way to do a multiple app updates at one shot.

Comment: On android you can use something called flavors for this. I haven't really explored into this but I think you can achieve what you are looking for using this method. Sorry for not being to help anymore than this.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS apps, you can create targets in the same app and for each target you can change the appicons, splash screen, theme color etc.

To create target, go to your Project, On Left side, under "TARGETS", you will see, two targets, one with your Project name, other with Test. Right click your project and click "Duplicate". Then you can rename the target. Also rename the target in "Manage Schemes", to avoid confusion later on. Then, you can change the app name seperately for all targets in "info" section. Similarly, you can create a different sets of Appicons and splash screens and use them for different targets. To change theme color, you can define a "Preprocessor Macro" in Build Settings and use it inside your code. You can set the macro's value for different targets.

Comment: In that case we will have multiple apps on App Store and I need to submit different builds for different clients?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do that but code will be the same.

Comment: Is this considered as "spamming" to App Store?

Comment: No, it is not considered spamming, but sometimes apple rejects the apps if same apps without any content change are submitted to the same account. For different accounts, I think it will accept it because App Store contains many similar apps

Comment: Interesting... The DropLocker apps are submitted under the same account and Apple didn't thinks it is spamming.